# Swift: overriding method with selector has incompatible type

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have declared a class method in Objective-C:

```
+ (id) someFunction:(NSDictionary *)param;
```

When I subclass the class and override this method in Swift with this:

```
override class func someFunction(param : NSDictionary) -> AnyObject?
```

I get the error:

> Overriding method with selector 'someFunction:' has incompatible type
>   '(NSDictionary) -> AnyObject?'

How do I override the method correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try to autocomplete that class function from somewhere else in Swift, Xcode tells me that `param` is an `[NSObject: AnyObject]!`, which makes the method declaration work:

```
override class func someFunction(param: [NSObject: AnyObject]!) -> AnyObject? {
    return "Foo"
}
```

This might be a compiler bug, since I'm pretty sure that's supposed to bridge properly to `NSDictionary!` (it seems to be bridging one way, but not the other, or something).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I did not get any auto-complete suggestions at all, but yours does work. It's no problem to cast the param, so that is a compiler bug I can live with.

Comment: does appear to be some sort of compiler bug, am running into that a lot myself